# Where to place business logic?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, service, frameworks

For example I want to build a project on top of the one PHP framework. At the moment I want to solve problem with `Auth` layer. I need to register a new user in a system and do some tasks after that.

So where I can place all of related business logic?

Now I'm thinking about `Services`. I want to create namespace `App\Services\Auth` where I'll put all classes related to the problem. There will be one `entrypoint` class that can be resolved within the DI container. This class will provide me method `registerUser`, `currentUser` and other methods related to the `Auth` layer. Also in this namespace I want to place `events listeners` like `SendEmailAfterRegistration` and other. So this namespace will contain all ecosystem related to the `Auth` layer. And only one class will provide me access to this whole ecosystem, that I can use in controllers.

Is it ok? Or maybe there are another more 'true' ways?

Comment: "layer" **is not a synonym of** "class"

Comment: @tereško Yes. There will be a bunch of classes related to the `Auth` layer. All stuff related to the `Auth` layer will be placed in `App\Services\Auth` namespace. I mean `layer` is a business-problem that we try to solve.

Comment: An alternative/optimization would be to split the entry point class (the service) into multiple _use case_ classes. A use case would perform what a method in your entry point class currently does (like, for example, `class RegisterUser`). The steps required to achieve the use case responsibility will involve the use of further specialized _domain services_ - the DIC will, of course, know to inject them properly. Their implementations will bring the other domain model constructs together (entities, abstractions of data mappers & repositories & external services & etc).

Comment: You can watch [this](http://confreaks.tv/videos/rubymidwest2011-keynote-architecture-the-lost-years) and [this](https://vimeo.com/130256611) if you wish.